# Python Web Scraping Not Getting the Desire Contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Web Scraping Noob here. I start my journey to stock investing, so I am trying to get data from Morningstar. However, I am not getting the data I want.

Take https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/financials as an example.
[image]

These will be the numbers I am interested.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/financials"
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

The status_code is 200, which is fine. However, the parsed page contents did not contain the numbers I want. For example, no result is returned for `soup.find_all('Price/Book')`.

I inspected the web page. The content stops at  tag where I marked red.

```py
soup.find("div", class_="mdc-column mds-layout-grid__col stock__content-sal mds-layout-grid__col--12 mds-layout-grid__col--auto-at-1092").contents
```

The code above returns an empty array. It should contain something () but does not. I don't think it has anything to do with js, but I don't know why beautiful soup fail to capture it either. Any hints are appreciated.

Hope I made myself clear enough.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the value of `page.content` in the script isn't the same as the content as seen in the browser, then it is to do with javascript not populating the page. Use a tool like [tag:selenium].

Comment: You can also use [`requests-html`](https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/), it relies on `requests` and supports javascript

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that site gets most of the data it displays through more requests once it loads. I can vouch for @crissal's suggestion, requests-html is basically like request and beautifulsoup in one.

Comment: Any of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/morningstar